# logstash apply multiple filters based on condition

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok

I have log lines as belows:

```
11:05:44,924 DEBUG DataFeed:? - Data received: data=TextMessage={ Header={ JMSMessageID={ID:someId} JMSDestination={Topic[someTopic]} JMSReplyTo={null} JMSDeliveryMode={NON_PERSISTENT} JMSRedelivered={false} JMSCorrelationID={null} JMSType={null} JMSTimestamp={Tue Aug 30 11:05:44 BST 2016} JMSExpiration={Tue Aug 30 11:06:44 BST 2016} JMSPriority={4} } Properties={ ACTION={String:ADD} XT_S_USER={String:someString} APPNAME={String:someFeeName} XT_BOOK={String:someBook} } Text={<?xml version="1.0"?><!DOCTYPE PSRequest><PSRequest><trade>..XML Tags..</trade></PSRequest>} }
```

I am trying to apply XML filter on the above log line which fails with:

```
:exception=>#<NoMethodError: undefined method `start_with?' for nil:NilClass>, :backtrace=>["/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-event-2.3.2-java/lib/logstash/event.rb:130:in `[]='", "/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-filter-xml-2.1.4/lib/logstash/filters/xml.rb:166:in `filter'", "/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.3.2-java/lib/logstash/filters/base.rb:151:in `multi_filter'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'", "/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.3.2-java/lib/logstash/filters/base.rb:148:in `multi_filter'", "(eval):41:in `filter_func'", "/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.3.2-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:267:in `filter_batch'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'", "org/jruby/RubyEnumerable.java:852:in `inject'", "/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.3.2-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:265:in `filter_batch'", "/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.3.2-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:223:in `worker_loop'", "/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.3.2-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:201:in `start_workers'"], :level=>:warn}
```

Also certain lines do not have XML content, I want to send them to a grok filter, how should I achieve this?

EDIT: 
Small snippet as to how to achieve below 
My case is something like this:

```
if(message.contains(certainText)) {
//apply grok filter and extract xml from it and send it to xml filter and then to ES
} else if(message.contains(someOtherText)) {
//Apply grok filter and extract key value pairs and send it to kv filter and then to ES
} else {
//straight away send that message to ES without any parsing.
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XML filter fail since the input is not valid XML.
You have to extract the XML and then use the XML filter. To extract the XML, you'll have to use the grok filter with this pattern:

```
%{GREEDYDATA} Text={%{GREEDYDATA:xml}} }
```

It will create a field named xml containing: `<?xml·version="1.0"?><!DOCTYPE·PSRequest><PSRequest><trade>..XML·Tags..</trade></PSRequest>`

Then you can use the xml filter on this field.

To send lines not containing XML to another grok filter, you can use [conditionals](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-dependent-configuration.html#conditionals) to separates part of your configuration. If you want a more precise answer, you'll have to add more information on your logs (it's better if you use another question to do so).

EDIT:

```
if [message] ~= /certainText/ {
   ...
} else if [message] ~= /someOtherText/ {
   ...
} else {
   ...
}
```

Comment: hi would u be able to suggest small snippet as to how to achieve the above snippet request..no need for internal details, but just how to achieve this syntactically